# Get Stuck When Opening a file with thousands of lines by LSP-enabled Vim on Windows MSYS2

Tags: lsp, filetype-c++, original-vim, windows, clangd

I am trying to recreate the Vim environment on Windows MSYS2 with my Linux Vim settings.

But I found that when the LSP (`prabirshrestha/vim-lsp`) is turned on, sometimes the file gets stuck when opening by Vim on Windows MSYS2.

For example, it will get stuck when opening a C++ file with 5000 lines or a python file with 6000 lines.

And it works well on Linux or Windows version gVim with the same device and Vim settings.

For C++ file, I have tried the clangd from MSYS2 package (`mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-clang-tools-extra 17.0.6-6`) and Windows version LLVM (`LLVM-17.0.1-win64`), but the results seem the same.

Does anyone know why there is a such big difference and how can I accelerate opening the file by Vim on Windows MSYS2?

Comment: I would report this to the plugin maintainers. Without that plugin (and sometimes by disabling syntax highlighting), I can open much larger files without any trouble

Comment: You should be grateful for your plugin's breakdown because now you finally have a reason to refactor that 5k loc mess into smaller, maintainable files. I know this comment's in vain but there, I said it.